# Is Cinnamon 5.2.7 incompatible with MenuLibre?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, cinnamon

I used Cinnamon 5.2.7 alongside Gnome 42.5 (Ubuntu Jammy 22.04). I tried MenuLibre application on Cinnamon 5.2.7. It caused crash. The Cinnamon reinstall did not help. I purged it completely. If I install it again it starts in crash mode, and I can only reboot. Gnome works normally. Is Cinnamon incompatible with MenuLibre application? How to restore normal start of Cinnamon?

Logs:

```
Bail out! ERROR:../libmenu/gmenu-tree.c:3795:preprocess_layout_info: assertion failed: (!directory->preprocessed)
```

Comment: This needs more info to be able to answer other than yes or no. It depends on what the cause is of the crash so please include that.

Comment: I have looked logs and have found error message. The gmenu-tree.c file, 3795.